# Julia panel data find data

Tags: julia

Suppose I have the following data.

```
dt = DataFrame(
    id = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,],                 
    t = [1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,5],
    val = randn(10)
)


Row  │ id     t      val       
     │ Int64  Int64  Float64   
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │     1      1   0.546673
   2 │     1      2  -0.817519
   3 │     1      3   0.201231
   4 │     1      4   0.856569
   5 │     1      5   1.8941
   6 │     2      1   0.240532
   7 │     2      2  -0.431824
   8 │     2      3   0.165137
   9 │     2      4   1.22958
  10 │     2      5  -0.424504
```

I want to make a dummy variable from t to t+2 whether the val>0.5.

For instance, I want to make val_gr_0.5 a new variable.

Could someone help me with how to do this?

```
Row  │ id     t      val        val_gr_0.5
     │ Int64  Int64  Float64   Float64
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │     1      1   0.546673  0 (search t:1 to 3)
   2 │     1      2  -0.817519  1 (search t:2 to 4)
   3 │     1      3   0.201231  1 (search t:3 to 5)
   4 │     1      4   0.856569  missing
   5 │     1      5   1.8941    missing
   6 │     2      1   0.240532  0 (search t:1 to 3)
   7 │     2      2  -0.431824  1 (search t:2 to 4)
   8 │     2      3   0.165137  1 (search t:3 to 5)
   9 │     2      4   1.22958   missing
  10 │     2      5  -0.424504  missing
```

Comment: what does `from t to t+2` has to do with it and what does search mean?

Answer (score 2):

```
julia> using DataFramesMeta

julia> function checkvals(subsetdf)
         vals = subsetdf[!, :val]
         length(vals) < 3 && return missing
         any(vals .> 0.5)
       end
checkvals (generic function with 1 method)

julia> for sdf in groupby(dt, :id)
         transform!(sdf, :t => ByRow(t -> checkvals(@subset(sdf, @byrow t <= :t <= t+2))) => :val_gr)
       end

julia> dt
10×4 DataFrame
 Row │ id     t      val         val_gr 
     │ Int64  Int64  Float64     Bool?  
─────┼──────────────────────────────────
   1 │     1      1   0.0619327   false
   2 │     1      2   0.278406    false
   3 │     1      3  -0.595824     true
   4 │     1      4   0.0466594   missing
   5 │     1      5   1.08579     missing
   6 │     2      1  -1.57656      true
   7 │     2      2   0.17594      true
   8 │     2      3   0.865381     true
   9 │     2      4   0.972024    missing
  10 │     2      5   1.54641     missing
```

Comment: (Let me know if you have any questions/need explanations.)

Answer (score 1):

first define a function

```
function run_max(x, window)
           window -= 1
           res = missings(eltype(x), length(x))
           for i in 1:length(x)-window
               res[i] = maximum(view(x, i:i+window))
           end
           res
       end
```

then use it in DataFrames.jl

```
dt.new = dt.val .> 0.5
transform!(groupby(dt,1), :new => x->run_max(x, 3))
```